# Jackson deserialize with Generics

Tags: scala, jackson

I´m trying to deserialize a json into scala class, that contains a Collection of types Aclass,Bclass or Cclass

```
class Results[M](results:util.ArrayList[M]) {

  def getResults:util.ArrayList[M]=results

  def this() {
    this(new util.ArrayList())
  }
}
```

The Json looks like:

```
{ "results":[{"a":1},{"a":1}]}
```

or

```
{ "results":[{"b":1},{"b":1}]}
```

or

```
{ "results":[{"b":1},{"b":1}]}
```

Here my object mapper

```
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
```

And here how I deserialize a json of class type Aclass

```
val results = mapper.readValue(json, classOf[Results[Aclass]])
```

The problem is that  results, return a ArrayList where every element instead to be an instance of Aclass, is a `LinkedHashMap`.

If I change the code instead to use generic I make it explicit in the type

```
class Results[Aclass](results:util.ArrayList[Aclass]) {

  def getResults:util.ArrayList[Aclass]=results

  def this() {
    this(new util.ArrayList())
  }
}
```

It works and return an class with result of array of Aclass elements.

What I´m doing wrong here?. I think it´s a bug in the library

Regards.

Comment: Are you stuck with jackson or could you also use a library that's not reflection-based (e.g. circe or argonaut)?

Comment: Completely open to use new libraries if does not require much code and achieve what I want. But anyway I manage to make it work using TypeFactory, but still not really happy how complex my solution looks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `java.lang.Class` does not hold information about generic parameters. The value of `classOf[Result[Aclass]]` is java.lang.Class. It does not have information about the type parameter `Aclass`. It represents only the `Results` class.

The mapper does what you ask for: gives you `Results` of whatever and the best whatever for it is a map.

To solve it, use readValue method that takes `JavaType` instead. `JavaType` can be created using `TypeFactory`:

```
val results:Results[Aclass] = mapper.readValue(json, mapper.getTypeFactory()
        .constructParametricType(classOf[Results[_]], classOf[Aclass]))
```

Comment: Seems like it cannot deserialize nothing. java.lang.ClassCastException: politrons.apple.search.model.Results cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing$

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add type declaration to val results. Without it, the type of is inferred to Nothing which is obviously not right at runtime. This is due to the unbound type parameter of this overload of the readValue method. I  have just updated the answer.

Comment: Finally I end up with another solution, using Play json but thanks!